# GridSearchCV saves only one estimator

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

How to save only one estimator of GridSearchCV? When I used the "joblib.dump" function, it generated hundreds of files for the "best_estimator_".

```
model=cv.best_estimator_
joblib.dump(model, 'model.pkl')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing the right thing.

The reason for you to get many `.pkl` files is that

> Note: joblib.dump returns a list of filenames. Each individual numpy array contained in the clf object is serialized as a separate file on the filesystem. All files are required in the same folder when reloading the model with joblib.load.

which can be found at http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html#persistence-example

Comment: @Arthur You can just read the `.pkl` file that doesn't have those underscores `_`. But all the files must be in the same folder.